# docker build creates another set of docker image even the build command is the same?

Tags: docker

Assume that you can create a 500MB docker image with following command

```
docker build -t demo:1.0 .
```

It seems to me that the docker image (`demo:1.0`) is overwritten when I re-run the same command. However, I noticed that free disk space decreases as I re-run the command. Why does this happen? Is docker creating another set of the image somewhere in the file system? I'd like to know how I can find old-generations of the docker images and delete them.

Answer (score 1):

It's standard docker behavior, if you run

```
docker images
```

you may see a dangling image like this

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED           VIRTUAL SIZE
demo                1.0                 a1b38444260e        6 days ago          500 MB
<none>              <none>              46250b7172c5        6 days ago          500 MB
```

You can remove the dangling images with the command

```
docker rmi $(docker images -qa -f "dangling=true")
```

Docker doesn’t delete such images automatically, despite, it's a logical feature to have. For now this command can be used to do a manual deletion.

While the images are stored in `/var/lib/docker/{driver-name}`, you wouldn't remove images manually from that path.

Comment: Thanks! The command could remove the dangling images. I'm using Boot2Docker on Windows. The host PC's disk space still decreases as I repeat building image. The host PC's disk space does not increase even after I run the command that you provided above against docker host. You might be noticed, but now I may be talking about Virtualbox that would create files on host PC's file system each time I build image... Does anyone have the same pain?

Comment: it's hardly docker related, you're right, this is  Virtualbox' virtual disk issue, maybe try to power off the vm at some point and watch it's size.